# Count value when

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table with temperatures multiple values every month for 21 years.

```
df <- data.frame(month=rep(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), times = 20, each = 3), 
                 year=rep(c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2020"), times = 1, each = 3),
                 Temperature=rep(c("4", "5", "6", "9", "10", "12","15", "16", "15", "14", "11", "8"), times = 20, each = 3))
```

The frame looks like that

```
df
```

I have done some analyses. I want to count for how many times  the mean temperatures(>8) of each month has been over a threshold on this timespan.
This is what I am trying but I have hit a wall.

```
countdf <- df |>
  group_by(month) |>
  summarise(Temperature = mean(Temperature))
```

Is it a solution to calculate the mean of each month for every year?

```
mean_tempJan <- df |>
  group_by(year) |>
  filter(month == "Jan")
  summarise(Temperature = mean(Temperature))
```

*EDIT* To be more clear I want to calculate how many months temperatures are higher than 8

Comment: Do you need `df |> type.convert(as.is = TRUE) |> group_by(year) |> summarise(n = sum(tapply(Temperature, month, FUN = mean) > 8, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: You can add multiple variables to `group_by` to make combinations - `df |> group_by(year, month) ...`

Comment: Change the Temperature variable to numeric. Now it is Character.

Comment: @akrun Is this month specific? Or it calculates the mean for each months on every year?

Comment: I understsand the question as you want the count of months that have mean temperature > 8 for each year

Comment: @thelatemail When I try it this way I get this message 
summarise()` has grouped output by 'month'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Comment: @akrun I did not quite understand what your code does.

Comment: ok, Your question as I read is `I want to count for how many times the mean temperatures(>8) of each month has been over a threshold on this timespan.`. My code does that

Comment: Maybe you should redo your sample dataset. Now you don't have Jan for each year, but ´"Apr 2013" "Aug 2017" "Dec 2020" "Feb 2011" "Jan 2010" "Jul 2016" "Jun 2015" "Mar 2012" "May 2014" "Nov 2020" "Oct 2019" "Sep 2018"´

Comment: @Bloxx I don't understand why it changed.

Comment: @akrun I must not understand something right since when I run your code it gives me back a nibble that don't much the data.frame

Comment: group by creates the attribute.  You can convert to data.frame with `as.data.frame`